Matrix whose determinant is a given polynomial
Given a homogeneous polynomial $f$ over $\mathbb Q$ of degree $d$ in $3$ variables, can we always find a $d\times d$ matrix with  linear form (over $\mathbb Q$) entries (possibly $0$) such that the determinant of this matrix is $f$? If this is easy, then let us additionally require that the matrix is dense (so no or very little $0$ entries). If the answer is yes, then why and is there a constructive procedure?
An example would be appropriate. Let's say $d=5$ and the polynomial is say $-yz^4+xz^4-x^3z^2/6+x^5/120$
Edit:
I have the solution of the above example. But I got it by just trying things. I think, the procedure I used to find the solution will not work for other polynomials. The matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
y-x & x & 0 & 0 &0 \\
x&0&z&0&0\\
0&0&x/6&0&z\\
0&0&0&z&x\\
0&-z&0&x/20&z
\end{pmatrix}$$
has a determinant that is the polynomial in the example. I don't have a solution for a dense matrix, but I think it should be doable. I wonder if there could be a general procedure for this.

Thanks. that was obviously a typo. I corrected it.

What is $f$?  Is it the homogenous polynomial?  Please [edit] your question to define what $f$ is.  What does "with linear form entries" mean?

Yes $f$ is the polynomial. I just edited the post. It means that the entries of the matrix are linear forms (i.e. linear homogenous polynomials).
